# Time Measuring from order placement to delivery in AnyLogic

Tags: time, anylogic

I'd like to measure the time from order placement (agent Order) to delivery to the shop.

There are some delays inbetween due to assembly of the goods. But after that I need to transport it to a defined port by trucks and vice versa in the country of destination.

I figuered I have to use sources (creates my good agents) and sinks (arrival of my good at destination) for timemeasuring. So I can use `TimeMeasureStart` and `TimeMeasureEnd` but I am having trouble with how I acutally implement this in my flowchart in AnyLogic.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Benj

Comment: read the help documentation and find the countless examples that use TimeMeasureStart and TimeMeasureEnd ...

Answer (score 0):

Create three parameters in your order agent: `timeEnter`, `timeLeave`, `timeInSystem`. When the order is created, set `agent.timeEnter=time()` and whenever you dispose of them, type

```
agent.timeLeave=time();
agent.timeInSystem=agent.timeLeave-agent.timeEnter;
```

You can add this value into a dataSet, for example.

Comment: and this will be logged in the database ? and I insert this code  then in the sink ? I am lacking the general understanding where to add what for getting the measure data (we are interested in km too)...

Comment: Yes, the second part is when you dispose of the agent. If you have Sink block, then there. Drag and drop DataSet from the pallette and add the timeInSystem information to that. At the end you can decide what to do with that dataset. Maybe write to Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time measure start and time measure end blocks.

You simply place the 'start' block where you want to start measuring and the 'end' block where you want to stop measuring and then refer to the associated start block inside the end block

[image]

The screenshot is from the how to model that can be found in the AnyLogic How to examples in the Software

Or check the link here https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/time-in-system.html#measuring-time-in-system

Comment: we found this too. But just have some statecharts instead of a general flow chart.  is it possible to insert `TimeMeasureStart` and `TimeMeasureEnd` there too? It does not connect

Comment: Your question says flowchart... not statecharts... You also mention sources... so are you doing a flowchart or just statecharts? And 'TimeMeasureStart' and 'TimeMeasureEnd' are Process Modeling Blocks and not part of statecharts...

Perhaps consider asking a new question about statecharts, I don't want to mix this answer with one for statecharts.